# Reference object in java

Tags: java, subclass, superclass, objectinstantiation

I have gone through many links about reference object in java. Still I don't have clear idea.

```
superclass obj = new subclass();
```

How will obj get instantiated? What is the use of it?

Comment: Please post at least one link out of many that you have gone through, that didn't make you understand this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`obj` is a reference variable whose type is `superclass`. That means that such a variable can point to an object of type `superclass` or any of its subclasses. In your case you are instantiating one such subclass, called `subclass` in your example. Now you can call any method on this object that is declared in `superclass`—and which the `subclass` is guaranteed to possess either by inheriting or by overriding.

Answer (score 0):

No, obj won't be instantiated (it is reference of type `superclass`). `Subclass()` will be instantiated and obj points to `subclass` instance.

I would suggest reading this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/object.html) to understand more about what does that mean object and reference.

Answer (score 0):

reference and object are two different things, reference may refer to one of the object (or it can be null, referring no where)

> how object gets initialized ?

there are lots of ways but in this example using new key word

> what is the use of it.

see polymorphism

Answer (score 0):

Here the `SuperClass` will hold the reference of the `SubClass` and the methods which are `overridden` by `SubClass` will be executed of the `SubClass` otherwise all the methods of the `SuperClass` will be executed.